# Unit testing promises attached to an AngularJS Scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

One of the many bits of magic AngularJS does for you is automatic promise resolution so that you can write code like this:

```
function SomeCtrl($scope, Resource) {
    $scope.items = Resource.query();
}
```

However, the service I'm working with functions via JSON-RPC and ngResource doesn't seem to play nicely with it. I've had to mock out the backend to respond appropriately, but for some reason I cannot seem to figure out how to test the response at the controller level.

```
"use strict";

describe('controllers', function() {

    describe('LibraryCtrl', function() {
        var scope, ctrl;

        beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {

            JsonRpc.respondWith({ some : data });

            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            ctrl = $controller(LibraryCtrl, { $scope : scope }); 
            // controller does `$scope.items = RPCService.get()`
        }));

        it("should create a `items` model with data fetched via JSON-RPC", function() {
            // here's where I'm very confused
            // JsonRpc does $httpBackend.flush()
            JsonRpc.respond();

            // now I want to inspect the property on the controller
            expect(scope.items).toEqualData( { some : data } );
        }); 
    }); 

});
```

The problem is, `scope.items` is a promise. That particular property will remain a promise, because apparently `$digest()` doesn't resolve the promise and re-attach the return value as the model value. I can't do a simple equality assertion.

My workaround is to use a promise capture mock:

```
var result = {
    capture : function(v) { result.value = v; },
    value   : null,
};
```

and then try this:

```
scope.items.then(result.capture);
expect(result.value).toEqualData(...);
```

This does work (but feels somehow wrong). As a sidenote (for brownie points, this isn't the actual question), swapping the `result.capture` chain with `JsonRpc.respond()` causes the test to fail (with `result.value` being null).

Here are the questions: what is the correct way to test promises set as scope models? Is this result.capture thing I'm doing okay, or is there a better way to go about it? Also, I'd really like to know why reversing the promise attachment with the response flushing causes the response to not resolve and capture...?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I'm experiencing the same issue.  I am currently working around it by doing something like Resource.query().then(function(value) { $scope.items = value }) but this is not very elegant...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048132/angularjs-promise-not-being-resolved-in-unit-test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. My first reaction is it seems your controller unit test is actually testing ngResource here. In my controller tests I mock out the resource:

```
mockResource = {query: jasmine.createSpy('query').andReturn([{id: 1, name: foo}])

module(function ($provide) {
   $provide.value('Resource', mockResource);

...

expect(mockResource.find).toHaveBeenCalled()
expect(scope.items)....
```

This allows you to test the controller in isolation.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I'm still not pleased about the automatic promise resolution happening in a way that I can't easily repurpose, but it does make sense that the scope of my test exceeds *just* the functionality of the controller. I appreciate the answer even if I've since moved away from using Angular ;)