# AngularJS: Unit Testing Directive w/ Promise returned from a Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, d3.js

I have a directive which uses a Service, calls a method of the service which returns a promise, and does work modifying the DOM inside the subsquent 'then' (myTestDirective below).

I'm trying to unit test this directive and when I run the test nothing inside of the 'then' is being called: the promise is rejected or the resolution not propagated?

I followed all the steps in [this post](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/06/angular-js-unit-testing-directives.html) to setup my unit test

When I load the directive in the browser I see both messages, ***OUTSIDE D3*** then ***INSIDE D3***, as you'd expect.

However in the unit test the element is updated only with the first message, like so:
`<my-test-directive>***OUTSIDE D3***</my-test-directive>` .
In the browser I see both messages.

Does anybody know what is going on here, do I need to inject mock or spyOn something?  Is this an async problem where the test runs before script tag finished loading?  I see the unit test accessing d3.v3.js, so it appears the script tag happens.  I have also unit tested the d3Service on it's own, and it worked. Once in a while I actually see the correct results without changing the test at all.

I see clues in this question but unable to understand how to apply it in my situation: [Angularjs promise not being resolved in unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048132/angularjs-promise-not-being-resolved-in-unit-test)

Here is the code:

**d3Service**:

```
var d3 = angular.module('d3', []);

d3.factory('d3Service', ['$document', '$q', '$rootScope', '$window',
    function($document, $q, $rootScope, $window) {
        var d = $q.defer();

        function onScriptLoad() {
            $rootScope.$apply(function() { d.resolve(window.d3); });
        }

        var scriptTag = $document[0].createElement('script');
        scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript'; 
        scriptTag.async = true;
        scriptTag.src = 'lib/d3.v3.js';

        scriptTag.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 'complete') onScriptLoad();
        }

        scriptTag.onload = onScriptLoad;

        var s = $document[0].getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        s.appendChild(scriptTag);

        return {
            d3: function() { return d.promise; }
        };

    }]);
```

**Directive**

```
var myDirectives = angular.module('myDirectives', ['d3']);

myDirectives.directive('myTestDirective', ['d3Service', '$window', 
    function(d3Service, $window) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',

            link: function(scope, ele, attrs) {

                var f = angular.element(ele[0])
                f.append('**OUTSIDE D3***')

                d3Service.d3().then(function(d3){    // Nothing here runs at all.
                    var e = angular.element(ele[0])  // In browser it works, but
                    e.append('***INSIDE D3***')      // not in the unit test.
                })
            }
        }           
    }])
```

**Unit Test**

```
describe('Test Directive', function(){

    var $scope, elem, compiled, html;

  beforeEach(function (){      
    module('myDirectives');    
    html = '<my-test-directive></my-test-directive>'; 
    inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
      $scope = $rootScope;
      elem = angular.element(html);
      compiled = $compile(elem)($scope);

      $scope.$digest();      
    });
  });   

    it('should create an svg element with its data', function(){
        console.log(elem) //outputs the element with only ***OUTSIDE D3***
    })

})
```

Thanks for any tips or information!!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I did was load d3.v3.js in my karma.conf and then create mockd3Service in unit test that return a promise.  If anybody know better solution let me know.

Here is new unit test that is working:

```
    describe('d3 Directives', function(){

        var $compile, $rootScope, $window, mockd3Service, $q, html, element, data;

        //setup test
        beforeEach(function(){
            mockd3Service = {}
            module('myDirectives')

            module(function($provide){
                $provide.value('d3Service', mockd3Service)
            })

            inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_, _$window_, _$q_) {
                $window = _$window_;
                $compile = _$compile_;
                $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
                $q = _$q_
            });

            mockd3Service.d3 = function() {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                deferred.resolve($window.d3)
                return deferred.promise;
            }

        });

        //run test
        it('make test', function(){
            html = '<my-directive data="testData"></my-directive>'
            element = angular.element(html)
            element = $compile(html)($rootScope)        
            $rootScope.testData = somedata
            $rootScope.$digest();

            expect(element...)

        })
    })
```