# How to test functions inside angularjs services using jasmine-karma

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am new to karma-jasmine testing.I have written one service which makes http get call to api and returns data object.

```
app.service('service_name',['$http',function($http){
    this.getData=function(urlPath){
        var Data = $http.get(path).success(function(data){
                var getData = data;
                console.log("getData success");
                return getData;
            }).error(function(response){
                var getData = response;
                console.log("getData error");
                return getData;
            });

        console.log(Data);
        return Data;
    };
}]);
```

From controller I am passing url to this service function and getting data using `.then()` callback;

```
service_name.getData(url).then(function(data){
    console.log('expected data: ', data);
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularjs promise not being resolved in unit test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048132/angularjs-promise-not-being-resolved-in-unit-test)

Comment: when I run my application on any browser all ajax calls are working fine.Those ajax calls are triggered on 'load' of controller.But when i run my karma testing configuration those controllers get loaded but all ajax calls are skipped.

Comment: You are showing code of the service than talking about controllers. What you want to test? If you want catch triggered calls from controller you must instatiate – http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2013/12/13/how-to-unit-test-controllers-in-angularjs-without-setting-your-hair-on-fire/

Comment: service_name.getData(url).then(function(data){
    console.log('expected data: ', data);
}); this code is written inside controller...thats why i mentioned controller

Comment: Please show your test … or better way, please fork this code http://jsfiddle.net/krzysztof_safjanowski/sDh35/ and implement your service and tests for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I did it:

First, setup the test environment according to this [article](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/advent2013/#!/day/19)

Then in the test spec, use the following test template to test your functions in service, thanks Ben Lesh for his great [blog](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/06/angular-js-unit-testing-services.html)

```js
'use strict';

describe('service_name', function() {
  var service_name,
    httpBackend,
    resource;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('yourAppName');

    // The injector ignores leading and trailing underscores here (i.e. _$httpBackend_).
    // This allows us to inject a service but then attach it to a variable
    // with the same name as the service in order to avoid a name conflict.
    inject(function($injector, _service_name_) {
      service_name = _service_name_;
      httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    });
  });

  // make sure no expectations were missed in your tests.
  // (e.g. expectGET or expectPOST)
  afterEach(function() {
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  it('should have a getData function', function() {
    expect(angular.isFunction(service_name.getData)).toBe(true);
  });

  it('getData function should return data object if http request is successful', function() {
    var expectedData = data;
    httpBackend.expectGET('urlPath')
      .respond(expectedData);

    var actualResult;
    service_name.getData().then(function(response) {
      actualResult = response;
    });

    httpBackend.flush();

    expect(actualResult).toEqual(expectedData);
  });

  it('getData should return error message when http request is unsuccessful', function() {
    httpBackend.expectGET('urlPath').respond(500);

    var promise = service_name.getData('urlPath'),
      result = null;

    promise.then(function(foo) {
      result = foo;
    }, function(reason) {
      result = reason;
    });
    httpBackend.flush();
    expect(result).toBe("getData error");
  });

});
```

Hope this helps.